# What is meant by interrupt remapping in Linux?

Tags: linux-kernel

Can anyone explain what the interrupt remapping is?

Would turning this feature off in the Linux kernel cause any problems, or bring any benefits?

Comment: Gory details [there](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel/704958)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas How about a full answer instead? That link is great.

Answer (score 4):

> Can anyone explain what the interrupt remapping is?

It's a software capability for rerouting signals sent from peripheral devices.

> Would turning this feature off in the Linux kernel cause any problems?

I believe this feature allows the kernel to replace the remapping tables created by your BIOS (which is also a piece of software), so if you turn it off, I guess it then becomes a question of how well the kernel and the BIOS remapping get along.

Comment: hi, today i have added the intremap=off in grub.conf file and started the server and sap application also running on that. till now its behaving perfect but don't know in future. i have gone through some blog saying that all Intel chip set 5520 and 5500 having bug with interrupt remapping feature. Anyone aware of this issue